# Why does `push` method precede `to_sym` method here

Tags: ruby, methods

This is a solution to an exercise in Codeacademy. Why does `symbols.push` precede `(s.to_sym)`? Why do the two methods appear in this order?

```
symbols = []

strings.each { |s| symbols.push s.to_sym }
```

Comment: It's not required. It's probably just showing you a basic way to transform the array of strings to a new array of symbols.

Comment: Which exercise? Provide the formula for what?

Comment: Quick quiz: What does `symbols.push(x)` do?

Comment: @tadman `(x)`is how many times to `push` i.e how many strings to push?

Comment: You need a better reference on what [`push`](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Array/push) does, then. In Ruby, since everything's an object, it's usually easy to find the documentation for a particular method, especially common ones like Array or Hash. It's a big toolbox, so spend a little time here and there familiarizing yourself with the various methods at your disposal. There's a tool for pretty much any job you could think of.

Comment: @tadman I've been doing RoR with OMRails and Harlt. Since my head was exploding i want solid understanding of Ruby before a get into Rails. I using the Ruby Pickaxe book, Code Academy and http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/. Thanks for the toolbox tip. I'll get on it.

Comment: Heh, the Poignant Guide is more surrealist art than a tutorial, but if it helps, that's great. The Pickaxe book has a reference section near the back which is worth browsing. There's a lot of methods in there to absorb. Start with String, Array, Hash and Fixnum to get started. You could also have fun with [Rails for Zombies](http://railsforzombies.org/).

Comment: @tadman it substitutes code for visuals which is very helpful for me for comprehension and retention. Yep, Rails for Zombies is on my list. Don't know about Fixnum's yet, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It only "precedes" syntactically. The order of operations is not strict left-to-right. Sub-expressions are evaluated as required. In this case `s.to_sym` is a sub-expression that becomes the parameter to the method `symbols.push`.

The parameters to a method have to be evaluated before the method is called, and the Ruby parser knows how to resolve this. So `s.to_sym` is called, and the result of that sent to `symbols.push`.

Ruby will also check precedence of operators such as `+` versus `*` to decide which sub-expressions to evaluate first in e.g. a maths formula.

Ruby method calling convention allows you to write function calls without parentheses, and this is quite common in Ruby code. It may help to understand that

```
symbols.push s.to_sym
```

is the same as

```
symbols.push( s.to_sym )
```

which is a syntax you will much more often see in other languages.

Importantly, the following is *not* the same:

```
symbols.push
s.to_sym
```

in that case Ruby will evaluate both expressions separately, and it will, quite happily do nothing useful for either line (specific to this case unfortunately because `push` is happy with no parameters).

Comment: You can read this as "`push` into `symbols` the value `s` transformed "to symbol"`.